# Is it necessary to use 'new' to allocate a new pointer to a struct identical to a previously existing pointer to the same struct? If so, why?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, new-operator

I am writing a function that inserts a new element in a singly linked linked list.

The function accepts the *head to the list, the data to be put in the new element and the position in the l-list should be inserted at.

[This](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list) is the link to the programming exercise in case I've not been clear enough.

The following code works perfectly -

```
/*
  Insert Node at a given position in a linked list 
  head can be NULL 
  First element in the linked list is at position 0
  Node is defined as 
  struct Node
  {
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
  }
*/

Node* InsertNth(Node *head, int data, int position)
{
    //Takes head of list as input and returns it after inserting a new element
    //with `data` at `position` in the l-list

    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp = head;
    Node *newn = new Node;
    newn->data = data;

    if(position == 0){
        newn->next = head;
        return newn;
    }

    while(--position){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    newn->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newn;

    return head;
}
```

However, I don't understand why I had to use `Node *temp = new Node; temp = head;`.

Why doesn't simply using `Node *temp = head;` work?
I'm only using the temp pointer to traverse the l-list so that I can preserve the location of the head when I return the final list.

**Edit - I understand that `Node *temp = head;` is the way to go. This was how I originally programmed it too, but I forgot to mention that this is what's giving me a *segfault*. When I change it to `Node *temp = new Node; temp = head;` it works for all the testcases(including the ones where head is NULL).**

**Why must this seemingly absurd mem allocation seem to make it work is what I want to know.**

Comment: How does it not work?  It should.

Comment: You are *not* allocating a pointer. You are allocating a Node, and receiving a pointer to the address of the newly allocated object. Here, you don't need to allocate a new Node, therefore a `new` expression is not needed

Answer (score 4):

The code you post above leaks.

```
Node *temp = new Node; temp = head;
```

This is no good.

```
Node *temp = head;
```

This is better.

There are other problems in your code; but your analysis that it was silly to new then immediately reassign the pointer is **correct**.  Well spotted.

Comment: I understand that `Node *temp = head;` is the way to go. This was how I originally programmed it too, but I forgot to mention that this is what's giving me a *segfault*. When I change it to `Node *temp = new Node; temp = head;` it works for all the testcases(including the ones where head is NULL).


**Why must this seemingly absurd mem allocation seem to make it work is what I want to know.**

Comment: @Krishnabm Because you have undefined behavior somewhere else?  Say, a dangling pointer you are using, and the extra allocation moves memory around in such a way that it doesn't cause the crash any more.  The fundamental reason is you are manually managing memory, and manually managing memory has proven to be hard.  Use `unique_ptr` for ownership, and it becomes *hard* to have danging pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The answers that were posted before mine are both wrong, sure they Point out that your code leaks, but they didn´t check the rest of the code to see if it actually does what it is supposed to do. Your code is prone to Errors, because you don´t account for the head being NULL, which is clearly stated.

```
// Returns the new node inserted at the given Position inside the l-list
Node* InsertNth(Node *head, int data, int position)
{
    Node *newn = new Node;
    newn->data = data;
    newn->next = 0;

    // No head, return node right away
    if(!head)
    {
        return newn;
    }
    // Exception - only case where head is not returned
    else if(!position)
    {
        newn->next = head;
        return newn;
    }

    // Create ´temp´ which is a pointer to the next node in the list
    Node *temp = head;
    // The function allows passing of a signed int, make sure we stay above 0
    // as the previously while(--position) would go into an endless loop
    // if a signed integer were passed on to the function
    while(--position > 0)
    {
        // Just incase the input is bad, and position exceeds the size of the list
        if(!temp->next)
        {
            break;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    // Now that we found the place in line, insert it between the temp and the next item
    // in the list. Which may also be NULL
    newn->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newn;
    return head;
}
```

Now as you can see a few changes were made, the code earlier on didn´t account for head being NULL, and it didn´t properly set the member ´next´ to 0, which would lead to a Crash eventually if someone iterated over the supposedly null-terminated single-linked list.

Comment: This code (as well as the code from the original question) will crash if `position` passed to the function is greater than the number of elements actually in the list (or if it is negative). So I would also add some protection against such inputs.

Comment: @MikhailP. Thank you for pointing it out, it was already protected from negative input. I forgot to add a safety check for the position being greater than the size of the list. Edited the answer for completion sake.

Comment: Thank you for what you've pointed out.

Also, @SirRogers - The code works for `head = NULL` (albeit in a very roundabout inefficient way) **ONLY** because the only possible value of `position` will be 0 in case of an empty l-list. Hence, the code will return `newn`.
My code is very bare and rudimentary, but I would like to know why I **had** to `new` the pointer to make this code work.

Comment: @MikhailP You are absolutely correct. my code would fail if the value of `position` is indeed greater. However, I did not safeguard against it intentionally because the code constraint in the link I provided clearly stated that `position` will always be a sane value.

Comment: @Krishnabm, I see. It's ok if you use this code only for that hackerrank assignment.

Comment: @Krishnabm Even if the assignment states that, in a production environment, working in a team, you can never be sure how your code is used or called. And making these "shortcuts" will have you maybe make them in a real assignment as well without you noticing. As humans we take up certain habits, and when you write code in a certain way long enough, it becomes a habit that´s not easy to get out of.

It´s like muscle memory, only your brain is the muscle. Force yourself to write proper code everytime, so that you become a better coder. Continuous self improvement. No shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Use of

```
Node *temp = new Node;
temp = head;
```

causes a memory leak. Memory allocated in the first line is lost. You need to use:

```
Node *temp = head;
```

Comment: Edit - I understand that `Node *temp = head;` is the way to go. This was how I originally programmed it too, but I forgot to mention that this is what's giving me a segfault. When I change it to `Node *temp = new Node; temp = head;` it works for all the testcases(including the ones where head is NULL).